# How do I get output from title_op() and address_op() functions into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

How do I get output from title_op() and address_op() functions into a data frame as below

title                                           Address
Silk Court                                     16 Ivimey Street, Bethnal Green, London E2 6LR
Westport Care Home                         14/26 Westport Street, Lime House, Wapping, London E1 0RA
Aspen Court Care Home                        17/21 Dod Street, Poplar, London E14 7EG
*etc*                                             *etc*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

#grabspage and parses it through ready for picking apart
my_url = "https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/lemonade/Documents/work/chromedriver')
driver.get(my_url)
page_s = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')




def title_op(page):
    title_container = page_s.select("div.home-name>p>a[href]")
    for container in title_container:
           titles = container.text.strip()
           print(titles)

def address_op(page):
    address_container = page_s.select("div.home-name>p.grey")
    for address in address_container:
        addresses = address.text 
        print(addresses)


title_op(page_s)

address_op(page_s)
```

OUTPUT

```
Silk Court
Westport Care Home
Aspen Court Care Home
Beaumont Court
Hawthorn Green Residential and Nursing Home
Coxley House
Toby Lodge
Hotel in the Park
34/35 Huddleston Close
Approach Lodge
16 Ivimey Street, Bethnal Green, London E2 6LR
14/26 Westport Street, Lime House, Wapping, London E1 0RA
17/21 Dod Street, Poplar, London E14 7EG
Beaumont Square, Stepney, London E1 4NA
82 Redmans Road, Stepney Green, London E1 3AG
28 Bow Road, Bow, London E3 4LN
141 White Horse Road, London E1 0NW
130 Sewardstone Road, Bethnal Green, London E2 9HN
Bethnal Green, London E2 9NR
2 Approach Road, London E2 9LY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting appropriate response then gather two lists and use zip then wrap with DataFrame call from pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# your code

page_s = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
titles = [i.text for i in page_s.select('.home-name [href]')]
addresses = [i.text for i in page_s.select('p.grey')]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(titles, addresses), columns = ['title','address'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! i used .strip() to make the rows cleaner. Very helpful!